# Complex CoreImage CIFilter pipeline recursively eats GBs of memory

Tags: swift, macos, metal, core-image

I'm writing a macOS app which performs a complicated chain of `CIFilter` operations on an image to greatly change the appearance of high resolution photographs, often 24 megapixels or larger.

Some of these effects included are gaussian blurs, unsharp masks, bloom, gloom, as well as a custom "grain" fragment shader I wrote in Metal using a custom `CIKernel`. The `CIContext` is using a Metal device to render it. Essentially, it's a long chain of `initialImage -> CIFilter -> outputImage -> CIFilter -> outputImage -> CIFilter -> ...`

Not only must all of these CIFilters be run in sequence for a final output, they must also be run on the full resolution for effects to be correctly scaled.

The problem I face is that executing entire process results in a massive usage of memory. With a 6000x4000 input image, the memory usage jumps to 6.6GiB while rendering.

I used the Metal instrumentation in Xcode to diagnose the problem and it seems that CoreImage is recursively allocating memory for each filter, so that memory just piles up and up until it can finally let go of all of the resources at the end.

I would have hoped this was sequential, releasing each source buffer before the next operation. I'm not sure exactly how to help the situation. Is there some way to pass each output image to the next filter, forcefully cleaning up each input `CIImage` rendering first?

[image: Metal Resource Events]

```swift
if let device = self.device,
   let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: descriptor),
   let queue = device.makeCommandQueue(),
   let buffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer() {
    
    let destination = CIRenderDestination(
        width: descriptor.width,
        height: descriptor.height,
        pixelFormat: self.colorPixelFormat,
        commandBuffer: buffer) {
            return texture
        }
    
    try! metalImage.context.context.startTask(toRender: metalImage.image, to: destination)
    self.renderedImage = texture
    
    buffer.commit()
}
```

Comment: Something in one of the videos might address this... https://developer.apple.com/videos/all-videos/?q=Core%20image

Comment: That's probably because you are saving an image object in memory at first and are using it there over and over.

Comment: @matt Thanks for this link. It helped me rewrite the filter pipeline and do some minor optimisations as well. I've now reduced the memory usage to 1.66GiB. Still expensive but far less. This video in particular was very helpful: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10008/

Comment: Thanks for reporting back! I'm no expert but I had a vague memory they had talked about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work well with only a few hundred MB of memory usage when displaying a 24 megapixel `CIImage` to an `NSImageView` without any CIContext.

```swift
let image = // Create CIImage from complex CIFilter pipeline

let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(ciImage: image)
let previewImage = NSImage(size: rep.size)
previewImage.addRepresentation(rep)
previewImageView?.image = previewImage
```

On a 5K iMac, it will render pretty efficiently for previewing (less than half a second to update). No `CIContexts` are needed until exporting the image using a `CGImageDestination`.